# Cannot play windows WMA lossless files on Rhythmbox

Tags: 10.10, music

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 with all its updates (without Windows) on it’s own drive and everything is working fine.

I want to play WMA audio files, also mp3 files. The mp3 files play fine. The WMA files do not play. Used "Rhythmbox Music Player" with and without "Ubuntu-restricted" -extras. Still does not play the lossless windows audio files.

I am frustrated with searching to play a WMA file ("download this converter"), but one cannot use this until one "deletes this". I have done everything but it still does not play my windows lossless files that I made from all my CD’s.

I am looking for a music player that I can use to play mp3’s and WMA lossless music files and automatically put the album cover on and update the info if one exists. Installation should be as simple as possible.

Right now I am back to the original virgin Ubuntu 10.10 with all the recent updates. This computer will do nothing but play music (mp3 and WMA) through a stereo system. I also use Internet to update album info for the music. I do not care what bells and whistles the music player program has, as long as it is an easy install and just plays my mp3 and wma lossless music files. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can get playback of WMA files by:

1. Adding the [medibuntu repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu).
2. Installing the package [non-free-codecs](http://packages.medibuntu.org/maverick/non-free-codecs.html).

The easiest way to do this is to open a terminal (Applications->Accessories->Terminal) and then paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) the following:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list ; sudo apt-get --quiet update ; sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring ; sudo apt-get --quiet update ; sudo apt-get --force-yes install app-install-data-medibuntu apport-hooks-medibuntu ; sudo apt-get --yes install non-free-codecs
```

Comment: better replace all the `;` by `&&` - and you would know if enything went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try installing package `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`  from the Software Center.

`apt-cache show gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` at least shows wma in the description.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi....Gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg is already installed. Just installed Banchee and the same happens when I try to play a windows wma lossless music file. It indicates that I need a "windows media audio decoder" and when it searches for one, it comes up with the Fluendo Complete Playback Pack for $34.95 which decodes "everything".....no thanks. I just want to play my windows lossless wma files.

Answer (score 0):

It is only in the last few weeks that the FFmpeg developers have produced a decoder for wma lossless, so most media players that use libavcodec will playback these files in the near future. By this I mean such players as vlc and MPlayer.

If you are running a 32bit system you should find that you can play wma lossless files using MPlayer + Smplayer after installing the w32codecs from Medibuntu.

Hope this helps :).