# I cannot play some WMA files

Tags: vlc, codecs, ubuntu-restricted-extras, drm, wma

I did a backup of several music files from my older Windows XP system. Now I can play *all* the `.MP3` files but not *all* the `.WMA`. **There are some kinds of WMA files that can be reproduced without problems**, may refute this in the picture below. The right file can be played, the left isn't.

[image]

I have long been looking different sites, Q&A from here, installing many packages but not luck. An example is [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/31053/62483).

What can I do?

My system: Ubuntu 11.10 32b. Player: Banshee & VLC

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The files are maybe protected by [Windows Media DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_DRM). One solution is to play and record them without [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) with your windows system, another is to use a tool like [FreeMe2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeme2/). You could also burn the files as audio cd and rip them again.

The Free Software Foundation calls it: ["Digital Restrictions Management"](http://www.fsf.org/campaigns/drm.html).

**Tip:** Stop using [*Windows Media Audio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Audio). Use another [audio file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format) such as [*Mp3*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) or if you are an idealist [*Ogg*](http://www.fsf.org/campaigns/playogg/en/) [*Vorbis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis). If you love lossless sound you could use [*FLAC*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC). See also the [comparison of audio formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_audio_formats).

[image: defective by design]

Comment: This seems likely. If some WMA files work, there's nothing wrong with the encoding, so they might be DRM protected because they were bought from somewhere where DRM was a standard.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE +1 Great answer. The files are from 2006, years where I have no idea of codecs, player, even of computer in general. Now my new music library are open files. Thanks and I'll hope more usefully answers like yours.